# Filter SQL server query offseting timezone

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone-offset

I have the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT Datetime,
       AccountTranID,
       CURRENT_TIMEZONE() AS server_TZ,
       Datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Arabic Standard Time' AS MENA_Time
FROM admin_all.DataFeed
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, Datetime, 23) BETWEEN '2019-11-22 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-23 00:00:00';
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Datetime                | AccountTranID | server_TZ                                       | MENA_Time                      |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-11-23 00:00:06.420 | 785620        | (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris | 2019-11-23 00:00:06.420 +03:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-11-23 00:00:10.193 | 785621        | (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris | 2019-11-23 00:00:10.193 +03:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-11-23 00:00:10.223 | 785622        | (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris | 2019-11-23 00:00:10.223 +03:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-11-23 00:00:24.236 | 785623        | (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris | 2019-11-23 00:00:24.237 +03:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-11-23 00:00:48.943 | 785624        | (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris | 2019-11-23 00:00:48.943 +03:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-11-23 00:01:06.636 | 785625        | (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris | 2019-11-23 00:01:06.637 +03:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------
```

I need to filter my results not by the current server UTC+1 date/time but by the MENA_Time
So for example, when filtering results between '2019-11-22 00:00:00' and 2019-11-23 00:00:00' it should be based on UTC +3 and not current server timezone definition (UTC+1)
Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: What is the data type of `DateTime`? (Side note, `DateTime` is a poor choice for a column's name, especially if it isn't a `datetime`.) If you're storing data where timezones are important, you should be storing it as a UTC time, or with the timezone. Some UTC+1 areas (Europe) use DST, so would a date in July actually be UTC+2? Do the DST dates line up to the UTC+3 timezone you want (does the UTC+3 timezone you use *even have* a DST period in the summer)?

Comment: Also, why are you converting the column `DateTime` to a `varchar` (of *unknown length*) in your `WHERE`?

Comment: why not convert the dates in the where clause itself?
    between convert(datetime,'2019-11-22 00:00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Arabic Standard Time'
AND
convert(datetime,'2019-11-23 00:00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Arabic Standard Time'